Can a single Cloudflare Zero Trust host server run multiple tunnels?
I use Cloudflare Zero Trust to access multiple VPCs that I manage. As a result, I have more than one Cloudflare account. To avoid switching between accounts on my WARP client, I am considering the possibility of adding a second tunnel from another account within a single host server.
For example, in this VPC, there is a host server running cloudflared with a tunnel that serves clients from their account for their corporate access. I want to add a second tunnel, but this one would be from my account.

You can run the multiple process of cloudflared on the single host, but to connect each VPC, WARP connection should be changed account-by-account.
